# Let $A$ and $B$ be events. Is it necessarily true that $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be events. Is it necessarily true that $\dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$?

If so, explain why. If not, give a counterexample.

---

I'm having a hard time proving this problem.  Where should I start?  How should I explain it in a way that makes sense and is a valid proof at the same time?  Listing random events wouldn't help since it must be true for all events.  Can someone walk me through this?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to switch $B$ and $A$ in the second fraction?  If not, just divide both sides by $P(A\cap B)$ and find some $P(A)\ne P(B)$

Comment: @SimpleArt  Sorry, is the equation I wrote equivalent to $P(A|B) = P(B|A)$?

Comment: what if P(A) = 1 and P(B) = 1/2 and we assume independence - then you get $P(A \cap B) = 1/2$ so  LHS = 1/2 and RHS = 1

Comment: A way of explaining it to be not true is that for independent events the equation boils down to P(A) = P(B)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$P(A|B)$ need not be equal to $P(B|A)$.

Let $A$ be the event that you get number $2$ from a dice toss.

Let $B$ be the event that you get an even number from the same dice toss.

Answer (score 4):

Say you have a standard six-sided die and a fair coin. You roll first the die and get $1,2,3,4,5,6$ with equal prob. and then throw the coin and get $H,T$ with equal prob.

Define $A$ to be "get a $1$ with the die" and $B$ "get a $Head$ with the coin".

Clearly $P(A) = 1/6$ and $P(B) = 1/2$ and both event are independent. Therefore
$$
\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{1/12}{1/6} \neq \frac{1/12}{1/2} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} 
$$

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B|A)=P(B)P(A|B)$$
We can see
$$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(A)}=P(B|A)$$
but
$$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B)P(A|B)}{P(B)}=P(A|B)$$
Hence,
$$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}\neq\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$$

The example is when $A$ and $B$ are independent. In such case $P(A|B)=P(A)$ but $P(B|A)=P(B)$

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, i think it does not(i might be wrong, but here we go).
Notice that $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} $ is actually the probability of the event $B$ knowing that the event $A$ happened. (Here, your sample space is actually the event $A$, so this formula is nothing but $P(C) = \frac{C}{S}$ where $C$ is an event and $S$ the sample space.
Now, think about it:
Is the probability of an event $A$, knowing that $B$ has happened,  equal to the probability of an event $B$, knowing that $A$ happened? The answer is no when $P(A)$ is not equal to $P(B)$. And that can be easily demonstrated:
You have:
$$ \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} $$
Obviously, this equality only holds if
$$P(A) = P(B) $$.
An example:
I have two dices, one black an one white. Let A be the event of the black resulting in 6 and B the event of the white resulting in 6.
I throw the first dice, so i have:
$$P(A) = 1/6 $$
And then:
$$P(B) = 1/6 $$
Since both of the events are independent, we have that
$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) $$
So:
$$P(A/B) = P(A) = P(B/A) = P(B) $$.
This is an example that the equality holds for $P(A) = P(B)$. Any case that this doesn't apply, the equality doesn't apply.